# SQL CLR function fails to impersonate when SQL Server is running as a domain account instead of SYSTEM or NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: .net, sql-server, impersonation, sqlclr

I have the following code working perfectly on a test box, which runs the MSSQLSERVER service as SYSTEM:

```
      currentIdentity = SqlContext.WindowsIdentity;
      impersonatedIdentity = currentIdentity.Impersonate();

       client.PreAuthenticate = true;
       client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
       client.Url = currentURL;

   /* Encrypt */
   try
   {
      encryptedText = client.Encrypt(plainText);
   }
   finally
    {
        if (impersonatedIdentity != null)
        {
            impersonatedIdentity.Undo();
        }
    }

        return encryptedText;
```

The basic idea of this function is to encrypt/decrypt text via a web service hosted internally. Whenever this function is called on a server that is running the MSSQLSERVER service as 'SYSTEM' or some other local account, the impersonation works fine. If the server is running the MSSQLSERVER service as a domain account (i.e. DOMAIN\sqlaccount), the credentials of 'DOMAIN\sqlaccount' are always passed to the web service, and impersonation does not seem to be working.

Is this expected behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, this works in the test environment where the database server and IIS server are the same machine. Testing from another server where the MSSQLSERVER service is running as a local account, out to another IIS machine yields the same results.

Answer (score 2):

For the service account that you're running your SQL server as, does that account have impersonation turned on?  There's a tab that's called  delegation in the properties window for the user within active directory.  You'll have the choice of not allowing delegation, allowing delegation indiscriminately, or configuring what services that account is authorized to delegate to.  The default is "no trust" which may be your issue.  Give it a look and see what you find.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I think that this is our issue, as we seem to be experiencing the double hop issue with IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Move your encryption function call out of SQLCLR. Making web service calls from SQL is a very very very bad idea. SQL Server resources are far too precious to waste them waiting on a HTTP response, even an internal intranet one. I have never ever encountered a reasonable explanation why to make the web service call from inside SQLCLR, other than short sighted coolness factor. Call the web service from the application, is the proper place to wait for HTTP responses.

Comment: I totally agree -- ESPECIALLY since SQL Server provides native encryption -- there should be no reason to leave the server.

Answer (score 0):

What protocol are you using for authentication?

If you are using Kerberos I would expect this behavior.  In Kerberos the SYSTEM and NETWORK SERVER SPNs are automatically defined.  However, if you want to use a custom service name you need to define an SPN (for that service name) for authentication to work.

Comment: I can see that the following SPN is registered for the domain account that is running MSSQLSERVER: "MSSQLSvc/servername.host.net:1433" Should there be one on the IIS side as well?

Comment: Sorry, we're actually using NTLM.

Comment: Is the web service set up to enable NTLM?  You need to set the impersonation = true in the config file.

Comment: Yes, the web service is setup for 'Integrated Windows authentication' in IIS. As for enabling impersonation there, it seems more that the problem is that the current user's credentials in SQL are not passed to IIS.